# Would they be muslim?

Tags: nikah, shahada

My friend is going to marry a Christian woman - they are having nikkah. The woman has not took shahada - but after nikkah will she be Muslim? As it is Muslim marriage?

Comment: How would nikkah have an impact on the faith or religion of a person without her/his active collaboration?

Answer (score 2):

Marrying a Muslim does not automatically make one a Muslim.
One becomes a Muslim by testifying the Shahadah (Ash Hadu An Laa Ilaaha Ila Allaau
Wa Ash Hadu Ana Muhammadan Rasululaahi [Abduhu Wa Rasuluhu].
When the Christian lady is ready and without coercion she can choose to become a Muslim.